# Dell iDrac SNMP information

Tags: dell, snmp, drac

Trying to get basic server information out of iDrac's SNMP protocol, I've run a full SNMP walk, then tried filtering. In neither of the two does it give me anymore information other than the iDrac NIC, I am looking for information from it for the other 4 NIC's the server has. I have iDrac 7 on this server. Is there a way to view that information over SNMP, maybe something that needs turned on? Below is my SNMP filtered walk command:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -cpublic 10.1.1.2 IF-MIB::ifEntry
```

Here is what it returns to me:

[image: SNMP Returned]

Comment: I'd expect such server detail get represented in the IDRAC MIB's rather than  the generic IF-MIB  i.e. oid  .1.3.6.1.4.1.674.10892.5.4.1100.90  rather than  .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2

Comment: I don't think you can get this information via SNMP (but I am not positive, hence a comment rather than an answer). The SNMP interface provides information *about the iDRAC*. To get information about the host system, you'll need to interact with the iDRAC using one of the system management APIs like Redfish or IPMI.

Comment: The command will be similar to what you've already used, but you'll replace the IP address with the IP address of the server, not the iDRAC.The iDRAC (Integrated Dell Remote Access Controller) is a separate hardware component on Dell servers and is not part of the server's main hardware. It has its own network interface, which is separate from the network interfaces of the server it manages

Comment: @AlexanderPavluchenko that only works if the server OS is running an SNMP service. Interacting with iDRAC via Redfish isn't dependent on the host OS configuration (and *will* get you information about network interfaces installed in the server).